# Change the strings for the times

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on my code as I'm checking on the `getTime1` to see if the strings is valid. If the strings is valid, I want to change the strings for the time to go 30 minutes backward in each time when the `getTime1` strings is valid.

Example: The `getTime1` strings show `12:00AM` so I want to change it to 30 minutes backward to make it to show `11:30PM`. If the `getTime1` strings show `12:30PM`, I want to change it to 30 minutes backward to make it to show `12:00PM`.

Here is the code:

```
getTime1 = self.getControl(344).getLabel()

if day_date >= 0 and day_date <= 6:
    if getTime1 == '12:00AM':
       self.getControl(344).setLabel('11:30PM')
    elif getTime1 == '12:30AM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('12:00AM')
    elif getTime1 == '1:00AM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('12:30AM')
    elif getTime1 == '1:30AM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('1:00AM')
    elif getTime1 == '2:00AM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('1:30AM')
    elif getTime1 == '2:30AM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('2:00AM')
    elif getTime1 == '3:00AM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('2:30AM')
    elif getTime1 == '3:30AM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('3:00AM')
    elif getTime1 == '4:00AM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('3:30AM')
    elif getTime1 == '4:30AM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('4:00AM')
    elif getTime1 == '5:00AM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('4:30AM')
    elif getTime1 == '5:30AM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('5:00AM')
    elif getTime1 == '6:00AM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('5:30AM')
    elif getTime1 == '6:30AM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('6:00AM')
    elif getTime1 == '7:00AM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('6:30AM')
    elif getTime1 == '7:30AM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('7:00AM')
    elif getTime1 == '8:00AM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('7:30AM')
    elif getTime1 == '8:30AM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('8:00AM')
    elif getTime1 == '9:00AM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('8:30AM')
    elif getTime1 == '9:30AM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('9:00AM')
    elif getTime1 == '10:00AM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('9:30AM')
    elif getTime1 == '10:30AM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('10:00AM')
    elif getTime1 == '11:00AM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('10:30AM')
    elif getTime1 == '11:30AM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('11:00AM')
    elif getTime1 == '12:00PM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('11:30AM')
    elif getTime1 == '12:30PM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('12:00PM')
    elif getTime1 == '1:00PM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('12:30PM')
    elif getTime1 == '1:30PM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('1:00PM')
    elif getTime1 == '2:00PM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('1:30PM')
    elif getTime1 == '2:30PM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('2:00PM')
    elif getTime1 == '3:00PM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('2:30PM')
    elif getTime1 == '3:30PM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('3:00PM')
    elif getTime1 == '4:00PM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('3:30PM')
    elif getTime1 == '4:30PM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('4:00PM')
    elif getTime1 == '5:00PM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('4:30PM')
    elif getTime1 == '5:30PM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('5:00PM')
    elif getTime1 == '6:00PM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('5:30PM')
    elif getTime1 == '6:30PM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('6:00PM')
    elif getTime1 == '7:00PM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('6:30PM')
    elif getTime1 == '7:30PM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('7:00PM')
    elif getTime1 == '8:00PM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('7:30PM')
    elif getTime1 == '8:30PM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('8:00PM')
    elif getTime1 == '9:00PM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('8:30PM')
    elif getTime1 == '9:30PM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('9:00PM')
    elif getTime1 == '10:00PM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('9:30PM')
    elif getTime1 == '10:30PM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('10:00PM')
    elif getTime1 == '11:00PM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('10:30PM')
    elif getTime1 == '11:30PM':
        self.getControl(344).setLabel('11:00PM')
```

But the problem is the `getTime1` strings will only show 12 hours time.

I'm wondered if there is a way if I could be able to reduce the code to make it to go with something like in 6-7 lines instead of 97 lines?

Comment: Holy cow! so many `if/elif` statements. Can you create a dictionary?

Comment: No, I can't create a dictionary as I have to use the code that I wrote but I am unable to find out how to reduce the `if/elif` statements. Maybe you could post an example how I could do that with 12 hours clock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
if getTime1 == '12:00AM':
    self.getControl(344).setLabel('11:30PM')
elif getTime1 == '12:00PM':
    self.getControl(344).setLabel('11:30AM')
else:
    ind = getTime1.find(':')
    if getTime1[ind+1:ind+3]=='30':
        getTime1 = getTime1[:ind]+':00'+getTime1[-2:]
        self.getControl(344).setLabel(getTime1)  
    else: 
        getTime1 = str(int(getTime1[:ind])-1)+':30'+getTime1[-2:]
        self.getControl(344).setLabel(getTime1)
```

Except for the two special cases, this program finds the `:`, checks if `30` is present, if it is then it keeps the current hour and makes a new string with `AM`/`PM` label and hour intact but with `00` instead of `30`. If the ending is `00` it turns the hour portion into an `int`, subtracts 1, turns it back to a string, adds `30` in the minute section and again preserves the `AM`/`PM` part.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are easier ways. You might be interested in the built-in [time module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html). It lets you parse strings and perform operations on them. You could also do something like:

```
time = time.split(':')
hour = int(time[0])
minute = int(time[1][:2])
```

And then you could figure out how to subtract 30 minutes. For validating you could use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: No, this is not the answer I am looking for. I am looking for the how to reduce the code the one I wrote as I want to change the strings. Example: `if getTime1 >= 12 and getTime1 <= 11:   self.getControl(344).setLabel(changetime + 'AM') else: self.getControl(344).setLabel(changetime + 'PM')` something like that but the problem is the `getTime1` will show the strings like `12:00AM`, `12:30AM`, `1:00AM` or whatever it is as it is a 12 hours clock?